# Spark 2.0 - number of core in session

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to set the number of core through a spark session in spark 2.0 ? 
This doesn't seem to work :

```
spark.stop()# was a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.cores.max", "5").appName("test")
```

Comment: You know that you can super-easily set that via the conf when you launch the job?

Comment: euh, no, I guess I don't : I am mainly using jupyter

Comment: I have never used that notebook. If you launch it by appending in your launch command this `--conf spark.executor.cores=4`, what happens?